# How to Style each feature in the same layer with different colors - OpenLayers 2

Tags: openlayers

The snippet given below gives  a brief idea on how I am adding features to the vector layer.

```
vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vector Layer");

drawControls = {                    
    Point1: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vectors, OpenLayers.Handler.Point),
    Point2: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vectors, OpenLayers.Handler.Point),
    Polygon1: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vectors, OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon),
    Polygon2: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(vectors, OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon) 
}

for( var key in drawControls ) {
    map.addControl(drawControls[key]);
}
```

How do I style each feature with different colours?.

I know I can style the vector layer as a whole with the code given below :

```
var defStyle_layer = { 
    strokeColor: "blue",
    fillColor: "blue"
};

var layer_style= OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults(defStyle_layer, OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style["default"]);

var layer_sm= new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
    'default': layer_style
}); 

vectors = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vector Layer", {stylemap:layer_sm })
```

I need help with styling each feature in the same vector layer separately.
The reason I need to place all these features in the same layer is because I want to have "UNDO" option

Comment: Should the styles be applied once the feature is finished, or while it is drawing? I have done this before using select feature and accessing the stylemap of each feature directly and I think you can do something similar using the featureAdded callback, but it would be quite fiddly to do it while drawing the feature (I think).

Comment: It would be great to know how to apply styles to features while drawing and also retaining the style as long as the feature is visible. If I change the stylemap based on the feature selected, the new style is getting reflected to the entire layer i.e. the features drawn earlier with a different style are changing to the current style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution to the question posted by me: Here is the code snippet given below:

```
<script src="lib/OpenLayers.js"></script>
<script src="lib/GeometricNet/UndoRedo.js"></script>
.......
.......
Rest of the code
.......
.......
var defStyle_point1 = {strokeColor: "Darkblue", strokeOpacity: "0.5", strokeWidth:3,  cursor: "pointer", fillColor: "Darkblue"};
var point1_style = OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults(defStyle_point1,OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style["default"]);
var point1_sm = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                    'default': point1_style
                    }); 

var defStyle_polygon1 = {strokeColor: "Red", strokeOpacity: "0.5", strokeWidth: 3, cursor: "pointer", fillColor: "Red"};
var polygon1_style = OpenLayers.Util.applyDefaults(defStyle_polygon1, Openlayers.Feature.Vector.style["default"]);
var polygon1_sm = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                    'default': polygon1_style
                    }); 


point1_layer= new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Point1 Layer",{styleMap: point1_sm});
polygon1_layer= new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Polygon1 Layer",{styleMap: polygon1_sm});

drawControls = {                    
                Point1: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(point1_layer, OpenLayers.Handler.Point),
                Polygon1: new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(polygon1_layer,OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon),
               }

for( var key in drawControls ) {
            map.addControl(drawControls[key]);
}

undoRedo = new UndoRedo([point1_layer,polygon1_layer]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following snippet achieves what you would like to.

You can use `${...}`interpolation within style definitions to refer to feature attributes. This way you can define styles per feature basis. Naturally you can also define other attributes to features and then define style rules to map to those attributes if defining color values within feature itself mixes data and presentation too much together in your case.

`sketchcomplete`-event lets you hook into creation of new features and alter their contents (in this case assigning a new attribute to a feature).

```
function init() {
  var map = new OpenLayers.Map("map");
  var style = new OpenLayers.Style({ fillColor: "${color}" });
  var styleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({ default: style });

  var wmsLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
                "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0?", {layers: 'basic'});
  var polygonLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Polygon Layer", { styleMap: styleMap });

  map.addLayers([wmsLayer, polygonLayer]);

  var drawFeatureControl = new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(polygonLayer, OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon);

  polygonLayer.events.register("sketchcomplete", drawFeatureControl, function(event) { event.feature.attributes.color = "#aa0000"; });

  map.addControl(drawFeatureControl);

  map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(0, 0), 3);

  drawFeatureControl.activate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must style each feature at creation time. Here is the constructor you chould use:

```
    var newFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(geometry, attributes, style);
    layer.addFeature(newFeature);
```

1. geometry - the geometry your feature represents
2. attributes - the optional attributes of your feature
3. style - your custom style

Hope it helps !

Comment: I managed to style each feature with a different style by putting each one in a a different layer.

Comment: According to my understanding the solution given by you is valid if it doesn't have to involve user's draw control. Having the user to dynamically draw features and to display each feature with a different style was possible by placing them in separate layers and styling each layer with a new color.I could also have undo option across different layers using [this library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/geometricnet/files/)

Comment: You can use the same layer with my solution and you can change the style of a feature while drawing simply by recreating the feature and adding your new style every time you want to change the style. I'm glad that you have found a solution to your problem.