# OpenLayers3 - Style each Feature individually

Tags: openlayers-3

I am adding features to a map by reading their WKT-String:

```
var feature = wkt.readFeature(entity.WellKnownText);
feature.bxObject = entity;
src.addFeature(feature);
```

Each feature has a bxObject-Property, and this Property contains the "radius"-Property.

I style the layer, to which the features are added like so:

```
var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: src,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 6,
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'blue',
                width: 1
            }),
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: [0, 0, 255, 0.1] })
        })
    })
});
```

I want the radius-Property of the style to be dynamic. What I did and works as a workaround is the following:

```
var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: src,
    style: function (feature, resolution) {
        return [
            new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                    radius: feature.bxObject.radius || 6,
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: 'blue',
                        width: 1
                    }),
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: [0, 0, 255, 0.1] })
                })
            })
        ];
    }
});
```

But this creates a new style for each feature... I potentially draw 100s of features and I even have the subjective opinion, that it slows everything down. **Is this really the way it is done?**

I found this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872464/how-to-style-each-feature-in-the-same-layer-with-different-colors-openlayers-2). But I had no luck trying to interpolate with "${...}". I guess this is an openLayers 2 feature:

```
var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: src,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: "${bxObject.radius}",
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'blue',
                width: 1
            }),
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({ color: [0, 0, 255, 0.1] })
        })
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is really the way, but you should keep a style cache and re-use when possible. See for instance: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/examples/kml-earthquakes.html

Comment: Thank you very much. I implemented the cache now - the interpolation feature would be great though.

Comment: As soon as you add selection and text then you have a style per feature (text/radius), per zoom (as I don't want to show the text in all zoomlevels) and per state (selected or not). This seems really awkard to me...